Is this grammartically correct sentence "這藥物讓你每天都是良好的狀態"？
Most AI say it is correct, for example Claude AI :
The sentence "這藥物讓你每天都是良好的狀態" is grammatically correct and means "This medicine keeps you in good condition every day" or "This medicine makes you feel good every day."

語法上沒有太大的問題；「是⋯的狀態」不是很通順，但也可以接受。「這種藥物能確保你每天都處於良好的狀態」這樣表述更好一些。

這藥 -物- 讓你每天保持在良好的狀態 ,  I'll say that

If "This medicine makes you feel good every day." is true, it might be a drug !?

If it is in a Chinese test it would be considered wrong.
Consider the phrase “你每天都是良好的狀態”. If you cancel all the adjective and adverb, you got “你是狀態”, which is considered as 搭配不当 (wrong matching of words), for the tangible 你(you) can't be a abstract concept as 狀態(mood).
To change that, you could change “狀態” into something not abstract, but it will change the topic of the sentence. A reasonable way to correct it is changing “是” into “保持”, for there's no problem for 你(you) to 保持(keep) 狀態(mood)
Also, it's not wise to ask AI about a thing that you can't answer it yourself by plain searching, especially when it come to Chinese grammar. My experience is that AI tend to believe what human input is always real, and they tend to answer a wrong "yes" than a wrong "no".

個人以為，狀態可能得分兩種；一個是健康狀態(身體),一個是亢奮狀態(精神)...當然 毒品也能造成這種狀態

@James 狀態 could have that two meanings, but both of them are abstract things that you can't turn into. As for drug...... Maybe. Drugs can be called as 藥物 sometimes.

"這藥物讓你每天都是良好的狀態". It sounds very weird. There are many mistakes in the sentence.

這藥物 sounds very weird. You can say "這種藥物" as a formal written expression or "這藥" like in oral language. Mixing the two sounds very strange.
是...狀態 is wrong. There is no such saying. (Like in English, you don't say "is frozen state", and you'd say "is in frozen state" or "is frozen".) You should say 有...狀態 (oral) or 處於...狀態 (written)。You can also add 一個 before 狀態 to make it a more complete sentence.
...讓你 is usually used for something emotional like listening to your favorite songs or seeing an old friend suddenly. It is also used more in oral language. Here the medicine is not something emotional. It should be "...使你", which just means "... make you ...".

Put the above three points together, the correct sentence can be:
這種藥物使你每天都處於一個良好的狀態 (very formal written language)
這種藥物使你每天都處於良好的狀態 (formal written language)
這種藥物使你每天都有一個良好的狀態 (casual written language)
這種藥物使你每天都有良好的狀態 (compact written language)
If you want a more oral sentence:
這藥讓你每天都處於一個良好的狀態 (sounds like TV Ads)
這藥讓你每天都處於良好的狀態 (still sounds like selling on TV)
這藥讓你每天都有一個良好的狀態 (casual)
這藥讓你每天都有良好的狀態 (very casual)
Basically the different combinations of those words have some subtle differences.

My first advice before anything, don't trust AI to translate something into another language. Sometimes the meaning could be understood, but just not the correct way to phrase it.
The correct version of it will be (1) 這藥物讓你每天都保持良好的狀態, or (2) 這藥物讓你每天都(擁)有良好的狀態, but not 這藥物讓你每天都是良好的狀態.
(To be clearer, 擁有 will make the flow smoother, but generally using 有 alone is acceptable)
The correct version will be translated into Chinese (not by an AI, lol) as (1) "This medicine let you keep the good shape everyday", (2) "This medicine let you have the good shape everyday". The wrong version will be "This medicine let you be good shape everyday".
Answer by Tec99 is not entirely correct, I will deem. Like in the sample sentence 你是我的世界 (You're my world), 世界 (world) in this context is abstract, however, it is still used together with 你 (you), a concrete noun.
My explanation is, you have used the improper auxiliary verb. 有 (to have) is a better choice here. 是 (to be) won't be accurate just like it is not in the English version of the same sentence.
P.S. FYI, you are currently typing Traditional Chinese in you query, thus the same font has been used in my answer. BTW, if you do not learn Traditional Chinese in purpose, and just wanted to learn Mandarin, Simplified Chinese will be a better choice. For it has simpler structure, less stokes, and is more universally available in places like Mainland China, the hometown of Chinese.

個人以為，狀態可能得分兩種；一個是健康狀態(身體),一個是亢奮狀態(精神)...當然 毒品也能造成這種狀態

这点我就不从而知了，只是按原文翻译而已
